# What is the chronological order of all the FNAF games (and book)?

Tags: five-nights-series

Basically, I'm trying to find out the correct order of the FNAF games, including the book, which seems to be the last.

Since there are five games out now, a lot of timelines are obsolete and don't include the FNAF Silver Eyes book.

Answer (score 7):

We don't know for certain the order as these are only theories but what we can deduce is that the order is:

1. **Five Nights at Freddy's 4** - 1983
2. **Sister Location** - (The date of this game is still very uncertain. The main theories is that it occurs at the same time as FNAF4 or in a more futuristic location)
3. **Five Nights at Freddy's 2** - 1987
4. **Five Nights at Freddy's: The Silver Eyes** - 1995
5. **Five Nights at Freddy's**
6. **Five Nights at Freddy's 3** +~30 years

Answer (score 3):

the CORRECT order is this:

- 1979/81 (unsure of exact date) Henry and William Afton co-own Fredbear's Family Diner together. Fredbear's Diner child (Silver Eyes
  protagonist Charlie's three-ish year old twin named Sammy in the
  books) is killed or kidnapped by William Afton (and presumably
  adopted as his youngest son in my personal timeline). Fredbear's closes and Henry, with his daughter Charlie, move to the nearby town and open the first Freddy's.
- Fnaf 4/SL
  (between '83 and '85) "Sammy" (FNAF 4 crying child) is about to have his birthday at the sister location to Henry's Freddy's Pizza (I will call it Fredbear's for now) and the older brother (possibly Michael Afton or a brother younger than him) shoves "Sammy" into the Fredbear and is injured. Afton promises to rebuild him and he eventually becomes the Puppet. He also "tests" the child with the Nightmare Animatronics in the underground facility seen in Sister Location. Baby at another restaurant Afton Robotics has connections to "scoops" Afton's young daughter (presumably pig-tailed girl with Springtrap toy from FNAF 4) likely killing her. he sends his oldest son Michael to the underground facility to investigate, but he is possessed by Ennard wearing him like a suit. Michael lives out his life for a while but soon coughs up Babys parts into the sewers since Ennard "no longer can be controlled by her". (she then presumably takes over William Afton similar to what happened to Michael Afton since that was their original target and now they are both the "Gollums" of society).
- Summer 1985. 
  William Afton uses Fredbear/"Springtrap" suits to murder 5 kids at Henry's restaurant, including Charlie's friend Michael who becomes Golden Freddy when the Puppet/"Sammy" gives them life. (not Michael Afton). Restaurant eventually closes and Henry commits suicide by Animatronic. Charlie moves out of town.
- FNAF 2 
  presumably new company called Fazbear Entertainment reopens Freddy's at a new location (presumably another town or city since novel characters never mention other locations). Bite of '87 causes problems for the company and the toy animatronics are scrapped by year end. restaurant either reopens Henry's location but gets barely any customers, or is opened at a completely different smaller budget location.
  -FNAF 1 (presumably 1993)
  Mike Schmidt (possibly one of the Aftons) works at the location after Phone Guy is killed by an animatronic or Afton in Springtrap suit. Afton (not sure which, possibly William) destroys the four main animatronics after the restaurant is closed, but ends up stuck or injured in the Springtrap costume. (He might have survived and been able to take the costume off. the books say he had scars from a past springlock failure. possibly the FNAF 3 mini-game event.) Afton possibly takes the dismantled animatronics back to Henry's location and probably rebuilds them.
- Silver Eyes novel in summer 1995 and The Twisted Ones one year later
  William Afton "night guards" the abandoned building that Henry owned. He has a five-night event with Charlie and her friends that results in him permanantly stuck in Springtrap suit. sometime in the future after the events of THe Twisted Ones, he is stuck in a room in an unspecified Freddy's location.
- FNAF 3 "Thirty years later"
  People looking to make money (possibly his son Michael who is looking for him) find Springtrap/William Afton and bring him to the Horror attraction Fazbear's Fright.

any gaps i made in this timeline you can probably fill in with what you know from the lore. the novels can STILL fit into the timeline (according to how i understand the lore).

Answer (score -1):

If you truly include the chronological order of both the games, and mini-games. it would most likely go like this:

- Fredbear's diner - 1987 (mini-game shows that the kid was bitten by fred bear himself after his brother put the fnaf character heads on to scare him)
- Fnaf1 - time is really unknown but this would be where five kids where killed by purple guy
- Fnaf4 + Fnafsl - both events took place together, since the play area itself was under the house of the same events of fnaf4. but fnaf four my have come before fnaf1
- fnaf 2 - The game would show that Mangle was created during the design of funtime foxy, this being when the facial reconization was going wrong because someone was messing with it. However, the old animatronics from fnaf 1 came in showing the breaking down process of the old gang.
- Fnaf 3 - most likely the near end of fnaf but *spoiler alert (possibly)* things changed and Springtrap escaped, Ennerd is still a factor, meaning possible room for a 6th game and possibly revealing the real chronological order of the games.

*This is just my theory.*

Comment: What is your reasoning behind your theory?

Answer (score -1):

the order I think is correct is

fnaf 3. Freddy is hiding something 'special' (baby)

fnaf 5. baby escapes into the pen and is seen as a threat so gets locked away

fnaf 4. The child is scared of the animatronics

fnaf 123. all at once. it is unproven which is first as whatever you think can be countered by something else. thereforeI think this is the child dreaming. I mean. why is there a grandfather clock in a kids pizzeria. you hear it when it turns 6. I cant explain the cheering but in fnaf 4 you actually see a grandfather clock which proves that it is the childs dream of escaping or whats going to happen to him.

I havent read the silver eyes but I have been recommended it and i have aso not played fnaf world. Fnaf six is out either at the end of this year or at the start of next year